# How do I plot a bar graph using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have pandas data frame like this

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  label
1  3  4  5  6  7    1
2  2  5  7  5  7    0
4  7  9  0  8  7    1
6  9  4  7  3  8    1
7  0  9  8  7  6    0
```

I want a bar graph which looks something like this - : [image]

I have tried using hist() function from pandas but I am not able to figure out how do I include label in the bar graph to get the following graph like the one in the image.

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to show the command that creates your sample input, such that we can easily construct the dataframe ourselves and test if the output is correct.

Comment: consider you have the above data frame. I used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) with counting by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) 
and last call [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df.groupby('label').cumcount(), columns=df.label, values=df.a).fillna(0)
print (df)
label    0    1
0      2.0  1.0
1      7.0  4.0
2      0.0  6.0

df.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph1]

Or maybe need aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['label', 'a']).size().unstack(0, fill_value=0)

df.plot.bar()
```

Using `piRSquared` data for better sample:

[image: graph2]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
df.groupby('label').a.value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0).plot.bar()
```

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(50, 6)),
    columns=list('abcdef')
).assign(label=np.random.randint(2, size=50))

print(df.head())

   a  b  c  d  e  f  label
0  0  2  7  3  8  7      0
1  0  6  8  6  0  2      0
2  0  4  9  7  3  2      0
3  4  3  3  6  7  7      0
4  4  5  3  7  5  9      1
```

---

***demo***

```
df.groupby('label').a.value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: It worked :-) df.groupby('label').a.value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0).plot.bar() regarding this line do u suggest any reading to understand the things from value_counts() function?

Comment: @NiranjanAgnihotri [***`value_counts`***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Comment: If I were to dynamically plot similar graphs for all the attributes in the data set, we have used name of attribute in the line of code df.groupby('label').a.value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0).plot.bar() how to dynamically do this for all the attributes? Taking name of attribute as a string variable is not working

Comment: @NiranjanAgnihotri `df.groupby('label')['col_name'].value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0).plot.bar()`

Comment: Worked :-) Regards